# called a jQuery function only over a specific width of window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this code on my site. I want to load this code only in a specific width of window.
For example, in the less than 768 pixels, this script will no longer be called.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var owl = jQuery('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
  rtl: true,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  loop: true,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1
    },
    600: {
      items: 3
    },
    1000: {
      items: 5
    }
      }
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's width function and then do something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

   if (jQuery( window ).width() > 768) {
      /// your code here
   }
});
```

[.width() Refernece](https://api.jquery.com/width/)

Comment: I used this, but the script is not called

Comment: the $ for jQuery is in your configuration not recognised, either replace with jQuery, as I did in my answer now, or use `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {`

Comment: Any errors? did you install jQuery? Does the original code work?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
if ($(window).width() < 768){
var owl = jQuery('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
 rtl: true,
 margin: 10,
 nav: true,
 loop: true,
 responsive: {
  0: {
   items: 1
 },
 600: {
  items: 3
 },
 1000: {
  items: 5
 }
  }
 })
 }
})
```

Comment: I used this, but the script is not called

Comment: Then try this
if((screen.width<768)) { #Code }

Comment: dear @vinee this worked. But the page should be refreshed. Can the page not refresh?

Comment: Try this code . This work without refresh.    
     $( window ).resize(function() {
     if ((screen.width<768)) {
      alert("hi");
  } 
 })

Comment: I replaced the code instead of alert("hi"); but did not work.

Comment: let me clear one thing owl-carousel only for less than 768px ?? if yes than what about greater than 768px. do you show owl-carousel slider ore not.

Comment: no only for more than 768px. But this code does not work for any size

Answer (score 0):

`if ($( window ).width() > 768){//ur code}`